# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - error

Tags: parsing, dom

I have this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://test.com/');
$class = $html->find("thisisatest", 0)->innertext;

echo $class;
?>
```

Error page:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xamp\htdocs\test\test.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Why do sometimes everything works fine and sometimes I am getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably useful to print the html to see what u are getting. The url be getting redirected. Probably helpful to use curl to get more consistent results and do error check